# How do I find files with "#" in their names, on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, files, search

I'm trying to locate all the files on my server which use a # as part of their name, and can't seem to get the servers' file search feature to restrict its result to only # files.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cmd`:

```
dir *#*.* /s
```